# Passing action to Android Intent using constructor and setter method

Tags: android, android-intent

I was have written to run simple android camera application to run it on android 4.

The code initially had camera intent defined as

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent();
cameraIntent.setType(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

When I tried to run this application it was throwing below exception :-

07-07 12:44:09.755: E/AndroidRuntime(11533): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { typ=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE }

However when I tried to run same program by defining "cameraIntent" as below it worked fine -

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

I thought passing "action" to intent through setter or through constructor would be same.

But it doesn't seems so, as passing "action" through setter method throws exception while passing it through constructor to new Intent works fine. Any idea why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code work fine:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent();
cameraIntent.setAction(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

instead of

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent();
cameraIntent.setType(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

becuase

[setType(String type)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) used for:

> Set an explicit MIME data type.

and

[setAction(String action)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) used for:

> Set the general action to be performed.